# Compare two arrays of objects and remove items in the second one that have the same property value

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

All I need to do is compare two arrays of objects and remove items in the second one that have the same property value. For example:

```
var a = [{'name':'bob', 'age':22}, {'name':'alice', 'age':12}, {'name':'mike', 'age':13}];
var b = [{'name':'bob', 'age':62}, {'name':'kevin', 'age':32}, {'name':'alice', 'age':32}];

function remove_duplicates(a, b) {
    for (var i = 0, len = a.length; i < len; i++) {
        for (var j = 0, len = b.length; j < len; j++) {
            if (a[i].name == b[j].name) {
                b.splice(j, 1);
            }
        }
    }

    console.log(a);
    console.log(b);

}

console.log(a);
console.log(b);

remove_duplicates(a,b);
```

I cannot understand why this does not work and instead gives:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined
```

What I expected was the following content in b:

```
[{'name':'kevin', 'age':32}];
```

Comment: Maybe because of redefinition of `len` variable in your loops

Answer (score 23, accepted):

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/Snippet/FC2fY/2/)**

```
 for (var i = 0, len = a.length; i < len; i++) { 
        for (var j = 0, len2 = b.length; j < len2; j++) { 
            if (a[i].name === b[j].name) {
                b.splice(j, 1);
                len2=b.length;
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 6):

Instead of using two loops you might also use the findIndex function:

```
for (var i = 0, len = a.length; i < len; i++) {
    var ItemIndex = b.findIndex(b => b.name === a[i].name);

    a.splice(ItemIndex, 1)
}
```

Or if you want to go completely without using a loop you might use the forEach function

```
a.forEach(function(item, index, array) {
    var ItemIndex = b.findIndex(b => b.name === item.name);

    a.splice(ItemIndex, 1)
}
```

Comment: Really loved this type of answer with updated syntax, like writing syntax without old-style for loops. 
Thank you so much.

Comment: *without using a loop*: most would count `forEach` as a loop though.

Answer (score 4):

Your problem is, that `splice()` will change the length of the array, so that your precalculated `len` value will be too large and the inside the loop you try to access undefined elements.

A possible solution would be to use the [`filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) method:

```
function remove_duplicates(a, b) {

  b = b.filter( function( item ) {
      for( var i=0, len=a.length; i<len; i++ ){
          if( a[i].name == item.name ) {
              return false;
          }
      }
      return true;
  });

  console.log(a);
  console.log(b);
}
```

[**Example Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/sf85H/)

Comment: Which will also fix the problem of the same `len` in the inner and outer `for` loop.

Answer (score 3):

You just need to **break** the inner loop when a match is found:

```
if (a[i].name == b[j].name) {
    b.splice(j, 1);
    break;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

You are starting loop from the `0`.

```
for (var i = 0, len = a.length; i < len; i++) {
        for (var j = 0, len = b.length; j < len-1; j++) {
            if (a[i].name == b[j].name) {
                b.splice(j, 1);
            }
        }
    }
```

[**Fiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/43cZ3/1/)

Answer (score 1):

compare and remove in array of object.Typically array of object data type may be typeOf is object.So that we need to convert into JSON stringify and then check condition..

```js
for(var i=0; i < a.length; i++) {
                    for(var j=0; j < b.length; j++) {
                        if(JSON.stringify(a[i])  == JSON.stringify(b[j])) {
                            a.splice(i, 1);
                        }
                    }
                }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
let A = [
  {name: 'a', age: 20},
  {name: 'b', age: 30},
  {name: 'c', age: 10},
]

let B = [
  {name: 'a', age: 20},
  {name: 'b', age: 40},
  {name: 'd', age: 10},
  {name: 'e', age: 20},
  {name: 'f', age: 10},
]

const compareName = (obj1, obj2)=>{
  return (obj1.name === obj2.name);
}

const compareAll = (obj1, obj2)=>{
  return (obj1.name === obj2.name && obj1.age=== obj2.age);
}

let output = B.filter(b=>{
  let indexFound = A.findIndex(a => compareName(a, b));
  return indexFound == -1;
})
```

Depending on which Objects you want to remove use:

1. compareName : Remove objects which have common name
2. compareAll : Remove objects which have both name & age common

Also to find common Objects list just add use `return index != -1`

PS: Refer my [Github](https://github.com/rahulxyz/DevelopmentKit/blob/master/Javascript/ArrayManipulation.md) for Array Data Manipulation examples in Javascript

Answer (score 1):

```
var a = [{ 'name': 'bob', 'age': 22 }, { 'name': 'alice', 'age': 12 }, { 'name': 'mike', 'age': 13 }, { 'name': 'keerthi', 'age': 62 }];
var b = [{ 'name': 'bob', 'age': 62 }, { 'name': 'kevin', 'age': 32 }, { 'name': 'alice', 'age': 32 }, { 'name': 'keerthi', 'age': 62 }];

a.map((firstObj) => {
      b.map((compareObj, i) => {
        if (firstObj.name === compareObj.name) {
          b.splice(i, 1);
    }
  })
})

console.log(b)
```

Comment: Don't use `map` when you don't use its return value. It is a waste of resources to have it create an array.

Answer (score 0):

The root cause is that you directly splice items from array b while you are in the for loop and pre condition is a and b have same number of items.