# Compare values in two arrays of obj and remove from first

Tags: javascript, angularjs

```
var firstOne = [
    { id: 22, value: 'hi there' },
    { id: 28, value: 'here' },
    { id: 77, value: 'what' }
];

var secondOne = [
    { id: 2, value: 'bond' },
    { id: 8, value: 'foobar' },
    { id: 87, value: 'what' }
];
```

I'm looking for the best approach to compare two arrays of objects by value. If value is same in both, then remove it from firstOne which would result in:

```
var firstOne = [
    { id: 22, value: 'hi there' },
    { id: 28, value: 'here' }
];

var secondOne = [
    { id: 2, value: 'bond' },
    { id: 8, value: 'foobar' },
    { id: 87, value: 'what' }
];
```

Javascript or Angular solutions would be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: We aren't a code writing service. Please write your own code and present a problem and we'll be glad to assist you

Comment: "Javascript or Angular solutions" is kind of like "pick up by car or Toyota Corolla". Angular is a framework *in JavaScript*.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Compare two arrays of objects and remove items in the second one that have the same property value](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17830390/compare-two-arrays-of-objects-and-remove-items-in-the-second-one-that-have-the-s)

Comment: @AndrewL. Roger that. I'll give it one more shot

Answer (score 1):

You could use [`Set`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set) for the filtering.

```js
var firstOne = [{ id: 22, value: 'hi there' }, { id: 28, value: 'here' }, { id: 77, value: 'what' }],
    secondOne = [{ id: 2, value: 'bond' }, { id: 8, value: 'foobar' }, { id: 87, value: 'what' }],
    mySet = new Set;

secondOne.forEach(function (a) {
    mySet.add(a.value);
});

firstOne = firstOne.filter(function (a) {
    return !mySet.has(a.value);
});

console.log(firstOne);
```

ES6

```js
var firstOne = [{ id: 22, value: 'hi there' }, { id: 28, value: 'here' }, { id: 77, value: 'what' }],
    secondOne = [{ id: 2, value: 'bond' }, { id: 8, value: 'foobar' }, { id: 87, value: 'what' }],
    mySet = new Set;

secondOne.forEach(a => mySet.add(a.value));
firstOne = firstOne.filter(a => !mySet.has(a.value));

console.log(firstOne);
```