# JS: Compare two Arrays and Remove Duplicate Values from one array by using search filter

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript

I have two arrays:

```
public favoriteTeams: any[] = [
  { name: 'Team Batman' },
  { name: 'Team Superman' },
  { name: 'Team Darkseid' },
  { name: 'Team Wonder Woman' }
];

public searchTeams: any[] = [
  { name: 'Team Iron Man' },
  { name: 'Team Spider Man' },
  { name: 'Team Ant Man' },
  { name: 'Team War Machine' },
  { name: 'Team Batman' },
  { name: 'Team Thor' }
];
```

I want to find duplicate items in both arrays and remove the duplicate value from one array by using `.filter` method.

Currently my filtering only searches in the initial array, but doesn't check another array to see if it has the found values in order to remove them.

```
public filterSearchTeams(name: string) {
  return this.searchTeams
    .filter(team => team.name.toLowerCase().indexOf(name.toLowerCase()) === 0);
}
```

Update: original class:

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core';
import {FormControl} from '@angular/forms';

import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Observable';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/startWith';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';

@Component({
  selector: 'dev-team-chooser',
  templateUrl: './dev-team-chooser.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./dev-team-chooser.component.css']
})
export class DevTeamChooserComponent {

  public favoriteTeamCtrl: FormControl;
  public searchTeamCtrl: FormControl;
  public foundTeams: Observable<any[]>;

  public favoriteTeams: any[] = [
    {name: 'Team Batman'},
    {name: 'Team Superman'},
    {name: 'Team Darkseid'},
    {name: 'Team Wonder Woman'}
  ];

  public searchTeams: any[] = [
    {name: 'Team Iron Man'},
    {name: 'Team Spider Man'},
    {name: 'Team Ant Man'},
    {name: 'Team War Machine'},
    {name: 'Team Batman'},
    {name: 'Team Thor'}
  ];

  constructor() {
    this.favoriteTeamCtrl = new FormControl();
    this.searchTeamCtrl = new FormControl();

    this.foundTeams = this.searchTeamCtrl.valueChanges
      .map(team => team ? this.filterSearchTeams(team) : this.searchTeams.slice());
  }

  public filterSearchTeams(name: string) {
    return this.searchTeams
      .filter(team => team.name.toLowerCase().indexOf(name.toLowerCase()) === 0)
      .filter(val => !this.favoriteTeams.includes(val));
  }

}
```

Comment: yes. maybe I'm blind?

Comment: I have tried a lot of variants. Trust me. Didn't solve my problem. This is the last construction I've tried: `.filter(val => !this.favoriteTeams.includes(val));` Didn't work. Still shows the batman in that team. Figures...

Comment: You would need to loop each time or use lodash

Comment: no one liner solution without lodash?

Comment: Maybe it's too late or I am working too much, but this doesn't remove the item from the array that has a duplicate item in the other array. Can you please provide the answer?

Comment: https://www.google.nl/search?q=filter+object+arrays+remove+duplicates+two+arrays

Comment: For example https://stackoverflow.com/a/17830547/295783

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/157608/discussion-between-deniss-m-and-mplungjan).

Comment: I’m on my mobile. Read the examples on the last search and use the script you like the most

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If somebody is interested in the end this was the solution:

```
  public filterSearchTeams(name: string) {
    return this.searchTeams
      .filter(team => team.name.toLowerCase().startsWith(name.toLowerCase()))
      .filter(team => !this.favoriteTeams.map(favTeam => favTeam.name).includes(team.name));
  }
```